# How can I transfer a PHP array via XML?

Tags: c#, php, file, serialization, urlencode

I have an XML document that is encrypted using a proprietary encryption program like so:
 `exec($programName, $outputArr, $returnVal);`

The resulting array (`$outputArr`) was serialized and stored as a blob in MySQL. I was making this encrypted array available on demand through a web interface. Basically deserializing and writing to a file on the fly.

Now the requirements have changed and I need to make this encrypted array available to another server which uses **.net/c#** and which in turn will host the web interface. We are using a REST API that responds to a GET request and sends out an XML response.

I tried writing the array into a temporary file and then retrieving the contents of the file using `file_get_contents($tempFile)` and then URL encoding the resulting string and putting that inside of the XML response that I was sending.

Of course, when the new web interface writes this out as a file (after URL decoding), it's nothing like it's supposed to be. By that, I mean our proprietary program throws up errors on reading this new resulting file ... somewhere along the way, there's data corruption happening.

We also tried a C# serialization library that deserialized PHP arrays into a c# primitive type but that wasn't a good solution either as it kept throwing up a bunch of errors.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's covered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml

Comment: I will try that, but mine is not an associative array and this would probably create invalid xml tag names...

Comment: Try JSON encode, then print the array. http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: Did you try base64_encoding instead of serialization?

Comment: @Oliver - I haven't. So you're saying that I should base64_encode() the resulting string from file_get_contents()?

Comment: If you want to put your data into an XML Scheme, that would be imho the best solutions.

Comment: thanks @Oliver - I'll try that and post an update here.

Comment: @Oliver - this solution worked quite well! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just access the working version, and re-manipulate it before sending to the new server...

```
<!-- Some XML based wrapper or other logic/output -->
<?php
  echo file_get_contents($url_to_working_web_interface);
?>
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion but there is no fixed resource on the web interface. It basically utilizes session information to generate a dynamic link which then just barfs the array into the browser and asks the browser to treat it as a file that's to be downloaded.

Comment: although this does make me wonder ... should I be using `file_get_contents()` or something else like `readfile()` or `fpassthru()` or just `fread()`?